# Can't compile any c++ file

Tags: c++, g++, sdl

I have this simple file, called `lol.c`

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    return(0);
}
```

From terminal, i type `g++ lol.c`

This is the output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:36:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/cwchar:44,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
             from lol.c:1:



/usr/include/stdio.h:30:22: fatal error: SDL_main.h: File o directory non esistente
 #include "SDL_main.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

I don't know if the problem is something with SDL, but when i try to run `../configure` to install it, i have this:

```
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

See `config.log' for more details
```

If is this needed, i can put config.log file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- you gave a  `.c` extension to a C++ source file; that is wrong, C++ files should have a `.cpp` (or `.cxx`, `.C`, `.c++`, the last two are a bit frowned upon) extension, or the compiler may try to compile it as C code;
- <del>you are invoking gcc instead of g++; this is wrong too, calling gcc on C++ files misses several options required to compile and link correctly (including, but not limited to, linking against the C++ standard library);</del> that was in an older revision of the question, now it says g++;
- but most importantly, your build environment is completely broken (some would say "FUBAR"); it is **not** normal that `/usr/include/stdio.h` includes stuff from SDL (the fact that it cannot be found is just a minor incident compared to this); you should really purge and reinstall anything related to gcc and to *the headers* of the C library; look for some libc6-dev package (or similar) to reinstall (be careful not to mess with the C library proper, or your system may be rendered essentially unbootable).

Answer (score 1):

You can't give `.c` (c extension) to a c++ file.

1 - Change it to `.cpp` (c++ extension, lol.cpp)

2 - You have to give options to g++ (in your case use -o to create executable file) `g++ lol.cpp -o nameofyourprogram`

3 - Execute through your terminal `./nameofyourprogram`

Comment: option 2 is not necessary. `-o` means to change the name of output file, it doesn't mean to create an executable.  The usage `g++ lol.cpp` without `-c` means to create an executable. The default output name will be used if you don't change the name with `-o`.